# The right way to redirect from herokuapp.com to custom domain with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, heroku

I'm dealing with a noob problem right now. I want to do a permanent redirection, with .htaccess, from a Heroku app domain to my custom domain.

I'm trying with this:

```
redirect 301 http://app.herokuapp.com/ http://mycustomdomain.com/
```

And no luck. app.herokuapp is still serving there, and no redirecting to mycustomdomain

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

Well, figured out by myself.  Was easy.

```
RewriteEngine On   

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^app.herokuapp.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mycustomdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Are you using Rails? I can't seem to get my .htaccess to register and nothing redirects. I copied your exact code and placed it in the root directory of my project.

Comment: Worth noting you must replace "app.herokuapp.com" with your Heroku app's domain. Worked for me on Laravel.